# Leaflet .openPopup() is not working properly

Tags: javascript, python, leaflet

unfortunately some of the code I am requesting help on is part of a more secure project. As such, I can't share full code snippets and can only share generalized peices, so I am sorry if this makes it harder to provide help.

POINT=MARKER

I have an app coded in Brython, but takes the same functionality as using Leaflet in JS. I have two functions for plotting markers on my map, one of which handles any and all points which would overlap each other (ones that have the same coordinates) and this function plots them as one point rather than two overlapping points. The other function handles all other non-overlapping points.

Every time a point is plotted from the function that handles normal unique points, the point/markers object is then stored to a global dictionary where it can be accessed by a unique ID, kind of like this:

{"id1": }

This allows me to edit the markers as I need to later in the code, and also allows me to call their popups to appear.

The second function, which again handles any and all overlapping points, does essentially the same thing and adds them to the same global dictionary with their ID.

Here is some code samples to explain it:

```
      point = window.L.marker([unit["location"][0], unit["location"][1]], {"icon": icon})
      point.bindPopup(desc)
      point.bindTooltip(unit["abbreviation"], {"permanent": True, "direction": "top", "className": "mainLabels"})
      collision.addLayer(point)
      allpoints[unit["abbreviation"]] = point
```

or, for the overlapping points handler:

```
          point = window.L.marker([coordunit["location"][0], coordunit["location"][1]], {"icon": icon})
          point.bindPopup(desc)
          point.bindTooltip(labeltitle[:-1], {"permanent": True, "direction": "top", "className": "mainLabels"})
          collision.addLayer(point)
          for abbreviation in abbreviations: # for every ID in the overlapping points because while they will show as the same point, in the code they need to be recognized as seperate points
            allpoints[abbreviation] = point
```

Then, I have a searchbar, which when a search result is clicked, the following code runs:

```
   def resultclick(evt): # Ran when a search result is clicked to take them to the specific unit
      name = evt.target.firstChild.textContent
      for unit in data:
        if unit["name"] == name:
          clearresults()
          point = allpoints[unit["abbreviation"]]
          timer.set_timeout(lambda: point.openPopup(), 500)
          map.setView([unit["location"][0], unit["location"][1]], 8)
```

And while this works for all the NORMAL points, it doesn't work for any of the overlapping points. No errors are shown in the console, I've made sure all the values are correct, I've double checked everything at least 3 times now and been troubleshooting for 2+ hours now, yet have not found a solution. Leaflet gives me nothing to go off to find a solution, and I don't know why this is happening or what to do. Anyone have any suggestions?

I am also using this plugin:
https://github.com/MazeMap/Leaflet.LayerGroup.Collision

Thanks!

I have tried everything, I swear I'm on the brink of tears I don't know why it's not working